# Should I disclose cheating incident if I am not asked?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cheating

I have been convicted for academic misconduct in my college some years back.

Now suppose I am applying for a program that does NOT ask about any academic misconduct. Would it be in my best interest to just tell them anyways? I know that telling the program would hurt me, but on the other hand, I feel that leaving this out would feel sort of like a "sin of omission"-type situation.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that your previous institution may list the incident on your transcript...

Answer (score 5):

Why complicate your life? Hopefully you have learned from your errors and moved on. I see no reason to bring it up, but would be careful to reply honestly to any questions that actually do arise.

Many students have some transgressions in their past. Many are never called to account. Most, we hope, overcome the need and tendency to cheat and develop better life skills.

I think that if you were intending to repeat bad behavior in the future then you wouldn't be asking a question like this. The application materials for graduate study never, to my knowledge, ask you why you should not be admitted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have definitely learned from my past mistakes - part of me still feels bad and guilty about what I did so it just seems like i'm..."getting off easy" if I'm not asked about my "record".

Comment: +1 - emphasis on honestly answer if asked about it.